# Debug with step filters in eclipse CDT

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

When I step into functions using Eclipse CDT, I often have to step in and out of many standard library and boost library functions before I get to the code I'm interested in. I think Eclipse JDT offers step filters that allow you to choose packages that are ignored when stepping in. I can't seem to turn them on for the CDT. There is a menu item in the Run menu but it is greyed out. Do they exist? How do I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse CDT is using gdb to step through the code. You need to run "skip" or "skip file X" in your gdb console in Eclipse. "skip" was added to gdb in v7.4.