# Eclipse CDT debugging (Step filters/avoiding library code)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, debugging, gdb

When I'm debugging C++ code in Eclipse, I'm forced to step through library code when I'd like to skip over those details and debug only the code that I've written. How do I do this? I've searched and haven't found a real answer.

Comment: just put debug point, where you want to debug & that will stop you where you had kept debug point.. to skip any irrelevant debugging, you can press F7..

Comment: Stack overflow reference link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507070/debug-with-step-filters-in-eclipse-cdt

Answer (score -1):

use `<F6>` to `step over` the call to the system function

rather than

using `<F5>` which `steps into` the call to the system function.

These two keystrokes are also shown as icons on the debug menu